# Creating files with a specified name,path and format from a object list

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

i need to create a bunch of files on my machine,currently i have a list of objects of type `FileInfo` that holds the name, path and format of the files that i need to create.

What would be the best way to go about this?i´m thinking of using a `foreach` loop, but my list has over 700000 objects and i´m not sure if that´s the best option.

Here's the function that i'm using to populate the list with the objects:

```
 public static  List<FileInfo> ReturnFileFromDBInfo()
            {
                var result = new List<FileInfo>();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

                conn.ConnectionString = @"data source = MYPC\SQLEXPRESS; database = MYDB; integrated security = TRUE";
                conn.Open();
                var query = "SELECT a.partNumber, b.fullPath,a.fileType,a.baseID FROM drawings a ,bases_bases b WHERE a.baseID = b.id";
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                   result.Add ( new FileInfo()
                   {
                       partNumber = dataReader["partNumber"].ToString(),
                       path = dataReader["fullPath"].ToString(),
                       fileType = dataReader["fileType"].ToString(),
                       baseID = dataReader["baseID"].ToString(),
                   });
                }

                return result;
            }
```

It´s just a simple query that retrieves the file names,path and formats from a sql-server DB

Comment: Skip adding them to the list and create them directly? Don't open the directory they get put in, unless you like making coffee :) ps; why do you need to make files? There are often better ways round such things

Comment: I´m just creating some dummy files to make sure that a function that i wrote to verify server vs DB inconsistencies is working :^)

Comment: Evolve. No one should be using old-joins via the where clause. NO ONE!

Comment: Could you explain why @SMor ?

Comment: [bad habits - old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Notice the date in that url! Similarly, single character aliases are a bad habit. Would the order of rows and file creation matter here? I'm guessing it might be useful for the disk to be accessing the same path until exhausted before moving to another (but that would be difficult to measure). Lastly, seek out knowledge and the experiences that others have documented rather than just wait for information to be passed to you. Experiment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a list of 700000 objects is going to be memory hungry and relatively slow. Instead of returning a List, I suggest you return IEnumerable, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> ReturnFileFromDBInfo()
{
    var result = new List<FileInfo>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = @"data source = MYPC\SQLEXPRESS; database = MYDB; integrated security = TRUE";
        conn.Open();
        var query = "SELECT a.partNumber, b.fullPath,a.fileType,a.baseID FROM drawings a ,bases_bases b WHERE a.baseID = b.id";
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
               yield return new FileInfo()
               {
                   partNumber = dataReader["partNumber"].ToString(),
                   path = dataReader["fullPath"].ToString(),
                   fileType = dataReader["fileType"].ToString(),
                   baseID = dataReader["baseID"].ToString(),
               };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will only create each FileInfo object as you iterate over the result returned by ReturnFileFromDBInfo:

```
foreach (var fileInfo in ReturnFileFromDBInfo())
{
    string fileName = fileInfo.ToString();
    // Create file etc.
}
```